# Infinispan as Hibernate 2LC: NamedCacheNotFoundException

Tags: java, hibernate, second-level-cache, infinispan

I currently use JBossCache 3.2 as a Hibernate 2nd level cache for clustered caching of entities in a EJB3 environment (GlassFish 2) which runs fine. Now I'm evaluating using Infinispan 4.2.1 instead and to my surprise I get `NamedCacheNotFoundException`s.

I use annotations at entity level like

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL, region = "myRegion")
```

and the exeptions are like

```
org.infinispan.CacheException: org.infinispan.manager.NamedCacheNotFoundException: Cache: myRegion
  at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.invokeRemotely(RpcManagerImpl.java:115)
  at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.invokeRemotely(RpcManagerImpl.java:126)
  at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.invokeRemotely(RpcManagerImpl.java:231)
  at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.invokeRemotely(RpcManagerImpl.java:218)
  at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.broadcastRpcCommand(RpcManagerImpl.java:201)
  at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.broadcastRpcCommand(RpcManagerImpl.java:194)
  at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvalidationInterceptor.invalidateAcrossCluster(InvalidationInterceptor.java:220)
  ....
```

Looking via jmx I can see a corresponding MBean but it's `CacheName` is like `myRegion(invalidation_sync)`. The suffix `(invalidation_sync)` seems to be added by Infinispan.

Is this the root cause of my problem? How to come around it? My Infinispan config is largely the one that comes with hibernate-infinsipan but with jmx enabled.

Comment: I think what's happening is that either: your EJB3 deployment is not deployed in all nodes in the cluster, or there's a timing issue to when your app is deployed. I'd try deploying the app in all nodes first and then trying to invoke operations on all nodes. Otherwise

Comment: Otherwise, I'd suggest moving to a higher Infinispan version. What Hibernate version are you using?